# Laravel Error reporting not show the file and line number causing error

Tags: php, xdebug, laravel

I got a error in my view then Laravel reported it like this:

```
Unhandled Exception
Message:

htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Location:

/var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/html.php on line 34

Stack Trace:

#0 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/laravel.php(40): Laravel\Error::native(2, 'htmlentities() ...', '/var/www/galltr...', 34)
#1 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(2, 'htmlentities() ...', '/var/www/galltr...', 34, Array)
#2 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/html.php(34): htmlentities(Object(Code), 3, 'UTF-8', false)
#3 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/form.php(454): Laravel\HTML::entities(Object(Code))
#4 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/form.php(406): Laravel\Form::option(0, Object(Code), '')
#5 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/bundles/former/src/Former/Fields/Select.php(133): Laravel\Form::select('label_type', Array, '', Array)
#6 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/bundles/former/src/Former/ControlGroup.php(170): Former\Fields\Select->__toString()
#7 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/bundles/former/src/Former/Former.php(196): Former\ControlGroup->wrapField(Object(Former\Fields\Select))
#8 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/view.php(354) : eval()'d code(45): Former\Former->__toString()
#9 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/view.php(354): eval()
#10 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/blade.php(71): Laravel\View->get()
#11 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))
#12 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/event.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#13 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/event.php(138): Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)
#14 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/view.php(325): Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)
#15 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/view.php(546): Laravel\View->render()
#16 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/response.php(246): Laravel\View->__toString()
#17 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/laravel.php(138): Laravel\Response->render()
#18 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/public/index.php(34): require('/var/www/galltr...')
#19 {main}

Unhandled Exception
Message:

Module 'xdebug' already loaded

Location:

Unknown on line 0
```

But for me, I yeild nothing from this report since it didn't show me the file and also the line in that file that caused the error. 
Is there any way to show the file and line number in that file that caused the error occured?

Comment: Or you can read the stack trace.


#4 /var/www/galltransweb/galltransweb/trunk/source/laravel/form.php(406): Laravel\Form::option(0, Object(Code), '')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As crynobone says it is in the stacktrace. Unfortunately with exception errors like this that come from internal core functions it can tell you where exactly the error occurs in the core but doesn't trace back to a mistake you may have made in your view to give that line number.

line 2 shows where htmlentities() was called and triggers the error handler in line 1

line 3 shows the form::option function that calls htmlentities()
line 4 shows the line with a return statement that is actually doing the calling of htmlentities()

So that tells you there is a problem in your view where you called Form::select()

looking at form::select in the source code, it is the $options array (second argument to Form::select()) that has a problem.

The problem being that it is expecting a string but is getting an object so double check your second argument to Form::select().